# What algorithms can be used to simulate a lens that is physically accurate?

Tags: algorithm, simulation, physics

I have never really done any optics stuff. Currently reading Optics by Hecht to get a deeper understanding of optics. I need to create a software that can take an image (a simple image, such as a red circle on a white background) and perform operations that will output an image that a person with Hyperopia (farsightedness) would see, when their eyes (or eye) are positioned on the centre of the circle. What algorithms can I use to model a lens for this purpose? Any reference to books, research papers, libraries appreciated.

Comment: The easiest way to emulate farsightedness is to just blur the image. The extent of the blur is afaik proportional to the distance of the actual focal point from the ideal focal point, so it depends on distance. Since you only have a 2D image, you have to embed it into a 3D scene (or at least emulate that by adding such parameters, as "distance between object and lense").
If you want something more physically accurate, you can use ray-casting to simulate the full-blown lens.

Comment: Chapter 6 of the book "Physically-Based Rendering" covers camera models in ray-tracing. [These slides](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cyy/courses/rendering/12fall/lectures/handouts/chap06_camera.pdf) from [this rendering course](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cyy/courses/rendering/12fall/lectures/) summarize the content of the chapter. It covers (amongst others) the roles of "depth of field", "focal distance" and "circle of confusion", "focal plane" and "image plane". Does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

[i deleted this post because i thought it was too light on details, but since no-one else is replying i've undeleted in case it helps.  recently i've found that there's a scientific computing s.o. that might be a better place to ask -  http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/]

it really depends on what you want to do.

for something as simple as a simulating what a farsighted person would see when looking at a (nearby) flat image, blurring (as suggested by Domi in comments) is probably fine.

things get progressively more complex when:

- what is being imaged contains components at different distances (in simple terms, the blurring for each will be different)
- you want to include exact effects of geometric aberrations (like chromatic aberrations on lenses)
- you want to include wave-like effects (like diffraction)

for general classical aberrations you have to do physically accurate ray tracing.  in practice you may find approximations that give good enough results in exchange for speed (for example, blurring is an extreme approximation).  for wave-like effects i am unsure - i guess you extend ray tracing with path lengths.

my copy of hecht is very old, but in the geometrical optics section there's a section on ray tracing, and that whole chapter covers the theory.

remember that, even if blurring is good enough, you still have to work out how much blurring from the exact details of the case, and the geometries involved (basically, you want the point spread function for your system; then you likely approximate that with a gaussian).